# Batch Script wanted (windows). find substrings in text file, and make specific changes based on positions of characters

Tags: windows, batch-file

(This is a Windows environment by the way.)
I'm new to batch scripting and, I'll be honest, I'm struggling.
I've done a lot of googling and spent a lot of time trying to work this out but I'm not getting very far.  I thought I'd throw this out to the community to see if anyone was up to the challenge. :)

First up, this is for my own personal use and curious interest to see if this is possible without writing a new .exe in a more... conventional language.

This is it : I'm using some software which is essentially portable.  the only downside is that it writes to a .ini file very specific file paths which may not necessarily be correct if using another computer.

For example, if I run the software from a USB in Computer A, that computer might see the USB drive as D: and save a path in the ini as **Path=D:\portables\soft1\saves\file1.xyz**.  But if I later use the same USB in Computer B which assigns a different letter to the drive (let's say **E:**) then the software will throw its toys out of the pram, because it's looking on the wrong drive for what should be now on E:.  And if I run the software from a network drive or even cloud storage then the path's get even more complex.

I want to run a script that might, before running the software's .exe, look in the .ini for all instances of such filepaths and replace the full path with simply **Path=.\saves\file1.xyz**.  The software is happy with this and can find what it needs to.

This is the ONLY thing that prevents the software being portable.

This is how I thought it would be done...

1. Search each line in the .ini, one at a time, to see if contains the
   substring "**Path=**"
2. If it finds it do the following...

   - a. Store the position of the character AFTER the "**=**" in "**Path=**" in a variable (let's say it's **vPosA=6**)
   - b. Search the same line for another substring "**\saves\**" and if it finds that then store the position of the character BEFORE the first "**\**" in another variable (let's say **vPosB=18**).
   - c. If vPosA and vPosB are both >0 then do the following

     - i. Replace all the characters on that line, from vPosA to vPosB, to "**.**"
     - ii. Reset vPosA and vPosB both back to "**0**"
3. Go to the next line and repeat the process until the end of file is reached, then overwrite the .ini with the changes.

I'm looking forward to seeing what people come up with.  Like I said, it's curiosity driving this.  If I get no answer, or it's way way too complex I may just write the thing in VB or something and use a .bat to run it before running the software.  The advantage of having it as a Batch Script is that it could shared with the software's community and the script is plain to see for all. With a compiled .exe people won't be able to see what's in it and would therefore, justifiably, distrust it.

Comment: Is there only one `Path=` line in the file? Are there special chars like `%`, `!`, `&`, `<``>`,`|`?

Comment: There can be any amount of 'Path=' lines.  and there shouldn't be any special characters at all, but not guaranteed (only what is normally permitted in filenames/paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (in.txt) do (
  set "line=%%a"  
  if /i "!line:~0,5!"=="Path=" set "line=Path=!line:*\saves=.\saves!"
  echo !line!
))>out.txt
type out.txt
```

Read every line, check if the first five characters are `Path=` (ignoring capitalization), if yes replace all from start to (including) "\saves" with ".\saves, append the string `Path=` in front of it. Print the line. Redirect the whole thing to another file.

You can then delete the original file and rename the new file to the old name.

NOTE: this ignores empty lines. It's possible to keep them with some more code.

Comment: That is perfection.  It does exactly what I need.  Much shorter and neater than I thought it would be and so quick!.  Thank you